# BlackBerry SDK 5.0 Issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I developed a Hello World application using Black Berry Eclipse plug-in. When I rant it on any BlackBerry simulator of which platform version is greater than or equal to 5.0 then the Hello World application is not found listed in the default application list. However, I can run the application from Options > Application : Search (Thridparty) and switch application. How can I make my application come to the default application list on any BlackBerry simulator with platform version is 5.0 or greater. 
My Hello World application is built for the JRE BlackBerry JRE 5.0.0

Can any one help....

Thanks,
Benoy Bose

Answer (score 1):

The application is located in the `Downloads` folder on the phone.

If this is not what you are looking for has an answer, please clarify your question.